# Let's get critical: Aug 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Network Engineering Stack Exchange](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [2960S IOS on 2950? Consequences?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/9847/2960s-ios-on-2950-consequences)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- ["simple" question about VLAN switching](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/9506/simple-question-about-vlan-switching)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Why can't we find wccp on 3550 cisco L3 switch?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/9686/why-cant-we-find-wccp-on-3550-cisco-l3-switch)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Cisco ME3x00 - QoS for layer 2 trunks](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/9363/cisco-me3x00-qos-for-layer-2-trunks)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Cisco FabricPath Simulation with Scapy](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/9733/cisco-fabricpath-simulation-with-scapy)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How are IP addresses mapped to MAC addresses?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/9612/how-are-ip-addresses-mapped-to-mac-addresses)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Does IEEE 802.11ac imply Wi-Fi Direct compatibility?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/9675/does-ieee-802-11ac-imply-wi-fi-direct-compatibility)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Cisco SG500X InterVLAN Routing Issue](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/9406/cisco-sg500x-intervlan-routing-issue)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Is it possible to avoid the traditional handoff when using Wi-Fi?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/9634/is-it-possible-to-avoid-the-traditional-handoff-when-using-wi-fi)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [No auto-negotiation for X520 with 10G direct attach cable?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/9432/no-auto-negotiation-for-x520-with-10g-direct-attach-cable)

**Net Score: -6** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 7)

---

Comment: So all I have gathered from the above is that 6 out of the 10 questions were sub-standard? That's it.

Comment: What I gathered is that 4 out of 10 are better than can be found elsewhere.  3 of 10 are about what you can find elsewhere.  The remaining 3 of 10 are not as good as what you can find elsewhere.  10 of 10 are worth revisiting by the community to see if we can improve them.  Two of them I didn't really have time to address when they were posted, so I took the opportunity  now to add my answers...which hopefully will improve them to some degree and make the community better and stronger.